# Haskell Parsec Parser for Encountering [...]

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm attempting to write a parser in Haskell using Parsec. Currently I have a program that can parse

```
test x [1,2,3] end
```

The code that does this is given as follows

```
testParser = do { 
  reserved "test"; 
  v <- identifier; 
  symbol "["; 
  l <- sepBy natural commaSep;
  symbol "]";
  p <- pParser;
  return $ Test v (List l) p
 } <?> "end"
```

where commaSep is defined as

```
commaSep        = skipMany1 (space <|> char ',')
```

Now is there some way for me to parse a similar statement, specifically:

```
test x [1...3] end
```

Being new to Haskell, and Parsec for that matter, I'm sure there's some nice concise way of doing this that I'm just not aware of. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks again.

Comment: Should the number of periods be constant or variable? Are spaces allowed between the numbers and periods, and between the periods? By the way, your first parser matches `test x [1 , ,2, ,,3] end`; maybe that's not what you want.

Comment: The number of periods should be constant, i.e. [1...3] should consist of exactly 3 periods for any case. Whitespace in between such as [  1 ... 3  ] should be ignored. Hopefully that clarifies what I'm after a bit more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll be using some functions from [`Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html) like [`(*>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v%3a-42--62-). These functions are useful if you want to avoid the monadic interface of Parsec and prefer the applicative interface, because the parsers become easier to read that way in my opinion.

If you aren't familiar with the basic applicative functions, leave a comment and I'll explain them. You can look them up on [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/) if you are unsure.

---

As I've understood your problem, you want a parser for some data structure like this:

```
data Test = Test String Numbers
data Numbers = List [Int] | Range Int Int
```

A parser that can parse such a data structure would look like this (I've not compiled the code, but it should work):

```
-- parses "test <identifier> [<numbers>] end"
testParser :: Parser Test
testParser =
  Test <$> reserved "test" *> identifier
       <*> symbol "[" *> numbersParser <* symbol "]"
       <*  reserved "end"
       <?> "test"

numbersParser :: Parser Numbers
numbersParser = try listParser <|> rangeParser

-- parses "<natural>, <natural>, <natural>" etc
listParser :: Parser Numbers
listParser =
  List <$> sepBy natural (symbol ",")
       <?> "list"

-- parses "<natural> ... <natural>"
rangeParser :: Parser Numbers
rangeParser =
  Range <$> natural <* symbol "..."
        <*> natural
        <?> "range"
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much, that's precisely what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: @VincentRusso it's a synonym for `fmap`.

Comment: Alright, one last thing I'm still trying to get right. Can I just do something like 

    l <- try( sepBy natural commaSep <|> natural symbol "..." natural);

Only, my implementation here does not work, is there something similar that I can do? Your example is great, but the way the parser is currently implemented appears to not play so nicely with the example above. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: Which part does not work? I don't have your `pParser`, so I can't parse the `end` part, so I just made it into a reserved token. You can of course do `l <- List <$> try listParser <|> Range <$> rangeParser` if you want to use your old solution, but the solution that I posted is essentially identical to your old solution; they just use different styles.

Comment: Yeah the different styles thing is throwing me for a loop as I'm a bit new to this so I apologize for my ignorance. I attempted to put in your suggested code in your comment, but am getting some errors that I'm not quite sure how to interpret. Sorry I can't be of more help in that regard.

Comment: In my original post, the only error I was receiving was a parse error that was of the form: **unexpected "."** **expecting digit, space, "," or "]"**. Is this what you are referring to, or are you referring to your post?

Comment: Hah, no, I meant that you should edit your original post to include the error message that you got.

Comment: Ah that's what I thought. Well, with your help, I eventually got to a point where it recognizes the [...] case. My solution isn't the most elegant, and I'll most likely go back and spend some time trying to make it a bit cleaner like yours. Just wanted to say thanks again for your patience and help. Cheers.