# Extracting Largest Number in Formated Textfile in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, max, parsec

Alright, I'm not sure if there's a straight forward way to this in Haskell, but here's my predicament.

Say I have a text file that contains the following:

```
map z [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] Z
test x [1,2,3] X
map y [1,2,3,4,5] Y
map q [1...4] Q
```

What I need to do is find the largest value contained in the map "list". For instance in the above example, the highest any map goes to is 7.
They are generally formatted as

```
map _ [] _
```

So I just need to find the max value held by the map in this example. Is there any straight forward way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, to be quite frank, I'm a little lost on how to get started. I'm just started learning Haskell so my knowledge on the subject is not quite up to speed. Perhaps if you could suggest a reasonable starting point that would push me in the correct direction, and I can follow-up from there?

Comment: 1) learn how to read the file.  2) Learn how to tokenize the file, parsing the strings into lists of integers 3) learn how to find the maximum of a list of integers 4) learn how to print to standard out. 5) Apply knowledge 6) ? 7) profit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My plan of attack would be something like this:

1. Sit down and carefully write out a grammar for the format I'm willing to accept.
2. Create an ADT which can store all (and only) the information available from a successful parsing of that format.
3. Write a Parsec parser. If you've done the previous two steps, this should be a cinch, though you'll need to learn a little bit about Parsec.
4. Write a function which processes the ADT designed in step 2 and extracts the statistics of interest.
5. Plumb the results of step 3 and 4 together; often, this is the most tedious and uninteresting part, but it needs to be done. =)

Let us know how far down the list you make it before you get stuck, and we can provide some more pointed advice.

Comment: He's made the parser, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525788/haskell-parsec-parser-for-encountering

Comment: @dflemstr To defend myself: he says above, "Well, to be quite frank, I'm a little lost on how to get started.". If that's not true, he needs to tell us the real place he got stuck, and we can't really do anything better to answer this question until then.

Comment: I assume he gave up on writing the parser and expects something "simpler" like `maximum . map (last . read . (!!2) . words) . lines`, which doesn't handle the `[1...2]` case or `[1, 2]` of course.

Answer (score 1):

If your file format is somewhat simple, you can write something like this:

```
process :: String -> String                                                    
process input = show . maximum $ map (maximum . readMapLine) goodLines         
        where                                                                  
            isGood line = head (words line) == "map"                           
            goodLines = filter isGood (lines input)                            
            readMapLine line = read ((words line) !! 2) :: [Integer]           


main :: IO ()                                                                  
main = do                                                                      
          input <- getContents                                                 
          print $ process input
```

I've omitted all the error checking, and my solution fails to `read` the last list in your file `[1...4]`: I presume it should just discard it. But you got the idea ;-)